# Align text widgets to start on the same position vertically

Tags: flutter

[image]Am trying to align text widgets located in the center of a row widget in flutter and I want them to start on the same positions (Across the marked line in the attached image). Similar to how they all end on the same position. Any ideas on how to achieve this?
Below is my code portion for the text column

```
[![Column(
            children: \[
             Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: \[
                Text(
                  "Meeting name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: kLightText,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),

                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: \[
                    Text(

                      general\["MEETING_NAME"\],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: kLightText,
                        fontSize: 10,
                      ),

                    ),
                  \],
                ),

              \],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            //MEETING LEADER
             Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: \[
                Text(
                  "Meeting leader",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: kLightText,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),

                Column(mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: \[
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text:
                        "${general\["FNAME"\]} - ${general\["LNAME"\]}",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: kLightText,
                          fontSize: 10,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  \],
                )

              \],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height:20,
            ),

            //MEETING DATE
            
                 Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: \[
                Text(
                  "Meeting date",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: kLightText,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),

                Text(
                  general\["MEETING_DATE"\],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: kLightText,
                    fontSize: 10,
                  ),textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,),

              \],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),

            //NEXT DATE
             Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: \[
                Text(
                  "Next meeting date",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: kLightText,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),

                Text(
                    general\["NEXT_MEETING"\],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: kLightText,
                      fontSize: 10,
                    )),

              \],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),

            //START TIME
             Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: \[
                Text(
                  "Start time",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: kLightText,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),

                Text(
                    general\["START_TIME"\],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: kLightText,
                      fontSize: 10,
                    )),

              \],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            //END TIME
          Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: \[
                Text(
                  "End time",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: kLightText,
                      fontSize: 10,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),

                Text(
                    general\["END_TIME"\],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: kLightText,
                      fontSize: 10,
                    )),

              \],
            ),
          \],),][1]][1]
```

Comment: please add an image

Comment: I've added an image

Comment: why not just use a datatable?? using a row with MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween would not always result in row items taking equal space so I would not rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is this

```
    Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```

spaceBetween puts as much as space possible between its children

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
         Text("Meeting Name", style: // Your style),
         Text("Meeting Leader"),
         Text("Metting Date"),
         ...
       ]
      )
    ),
   Expanded(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
         Text("Value of Meeting Name", style: // Your style),
         Text("Value of Meeting Leader"),
         Text("Value of Metting Date"),
         ...
       ]
      )
    ),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

in Row widget replace

```
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```

with ;

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Wrap your Column inside a Flexible Widget like this

```
Flexible(
child: Column(
  children: [
    Row(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Add items',
            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ]),
    Row(children: [
      Text(
        'Add items to your playlist',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontSize: 13),
      ),
    ])
  ],
))
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation here? That will be more helpful to other users